# React + Typescript - How to handle waiting for an API to complete

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a interface (simplified) like such:

```
export interface Chapter{
    id: string,
    code: string
}
```

In a component I'm then making a API call like such:

```
componentDidMount() {
        fetch("https://someapi/getchapter")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => this.setState({ chapter: response, doneFetching: true }))
            .catch(() => this.setState({ errorRetrievingSeries: true }));
}
```

At the start of the component I've set state like this:

```
state = {
        doneFetching: false,
        errorRetrievingSeries: false,
        chapter: {}
};
```

My my question/trouble is when I call `render` - I'll end up getting `chapter.id` being null as `componentDidMount` would not have got the results.

```
render() {
   const chapter = this.state.chapter;

   return (
      <h4>Chapter #{chapter.id}</h4>
   )
}
```

So my question is how do I handle such situations? That interface Chapter is actually quite long, so I don't want to go and initialise everything as an empty string `""` or whatever the type is.

Is there something in either Typescript whereby I can say, trust me something is coming?
Or is there some React approach to help.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check if its `doneFetching` or `errorRetrievingSeries` before returning the chapter

Also set `doneFetching` to true when an error occurs

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch("https://someapi/getchapter")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => this.setState({ chapter: response, doneFetching: true }))
    .catch(() => this.setState({ errorRetrievingSeries: true, doneFetching: true }));
}

render() {
  const { doneFetching, errorRetrievingSeries, chapter} = this.state;

  if (!doneFetching) return <span>fetching...</span>;
  if (errorRetrievingSeries) return <span>Something went wrong</span>;

  return (
    <h4>Chapter #{chapter.id}</h4>
  );
}
```

Or if you don't care about the other states you can just set chapter to `null` and render based on chapter

```
state = { chapter: null }

render() {
  const { chapter} = this.state;

  if (!chapter) return null;

  return (
    <h4>Chapter #{chapter.id}</h4>
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried the first method already - but I keep getting the error `Property 'id' does not exist on type '{}'.  TS2339`

Comment: @userMod2 how your state interface looks like ?

Comment: Its in my original post at the top

Comment: @userMod2 Your component state interface not the chapter interface